# C# XML get nodes based on attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml:

```
<root ...>
  <Tables>
    <Table content="..">
    </Table>
    <Table content="interesting">
      <Item ...></Item>
      <Item ...></Item>
      <Item ...></Item>
    </Table>
    ...etc...
  </Tables>
</root>
```

I'm using the following code to get the items from the 'interesting' node:

```
XElement xel = XElement.Parse(resp);

var nodes = from n in xel.Elements("Tables").Elements("Table")
            where n.Attribute("content").Value == "interesting"
            select n;

var items = from i in nodes.Elements()
            select i;
```

Is there a simpler, cleaner way to achieve this?

Comment: That's not valid XML... the first Table doesn't have an endtag called Table...

Comment: I really prefer to use `XmlSerializer` over `XElement` or `XmlDocument`.

Comment: @Fendy XDocument > XmlSerializer > XmlDocument

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well there's no point in using a query expression for `items`, and you can wrap the whole thing up very easily in a single statement. I wouldn't even bother with a query expression for that:

```
var items = XElement.Parse(resp)
                    .Elements("Tables")
                    .Elements("Table")
                    .Where(n => n.Attribute("content").Value == "interesting")
                    .Elements();
```

Note that this (and your current query) will throw an exception for any `Table` element without a `content` attribute. If you'd rather just skip it, you can use:

```
.Where(n => (string) n.Attribute("content") == "interesting")
```

instead.

Comment: Good point on casting attribute instead of accessing `Value` property

Answer (score 2):

You can use XPath (extension is in *System.Xml.XPath* namespace) to select all items in one line:

```
var items = xel.XPathSelectElements("//Table[@content='interesting']/Item");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need `nodes` outside of your query for `items`, you can just do this:

```
var items = from n in xel.Elements("Tables").Elements("Table")
            where n.Attribute("content").Value == "interesting"
            from i in n.Elements()
            select i;
```

Answer (score 1):

using xml document
  XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();

var item= xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("Table[@content='interesting']/Item");